# Get both matched and unmatched records mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to list all the documents from  myCollection ,In the order of  matched document should be first and others to be next.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(
    [    {
                    $match: {
                        $and: [
                            {
                                $or: matchArray
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                } ]
);
```

I used the above query for matched and $nin for unmatched document in separate queries.But I need single query to achieve this.

Can anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: Can you add a sample document from the collection to the piost? How does your `matchArray` looks like ?

Comment: For example, matchArray = [{status:"active"},{status:"open"},{status:"Inprogress"}]

Comment: No $match needed here. Pass an array of status and use `$in` to generate a sort field order. Sort desc to show matched documents at  top followed by unmatched documents. Something like should work `db.col.aggregate([
     {"$addFields":{ "sortorder":{"$indexOfArray":[["active","open","Inprogress"], "$status"]}}}, 
     {"$sort":{"sortorder":-1}},
     {"$project":{"sortorder":0}}
    ])` in 3.4

Comment: Perfect! Working like a charm. Thank you :-) @Veeram